# How can I describe walking through a strong wind?

Tags: word-choice

I've thought about: "pushing/muscling through the wind"

Comment: First think about what type of wind it is. Hurricane force? A slight breeze? You can use just about any word, it just depends on what effect you want. Provide more context if you still need help finding the right word.

Comment: It would be a very strong wind.

Comment: Great! So it's pretty much personal preference. For example, I don't care for "muscling through the wind", but it does get the point across. You could use any synonym for your given options. Or, try a different wording. "I struggled to walk into the wind." or "The wind tried sweeping my feet from under me as I made my way home from work."

Comment: Battling the wind ...

Comment: Plow is often used to describe movement through resistance whether it be waves, snow or wind.

Comment: Leaning into the wind.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bent+into+the+wind%2Chunched+into+the+wind%2Cleaned+into+the+wind&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbent%20into%20the%20wind%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chunched%20into%20the%20wind%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cleaned%20into%20the%20wind%3B%2Cc0

Comment: As you may know, American bison have considerably thicker fur on the front half of their bodies than on the back half, and they habitually face into the wind when a blizzard or other storm is blowing. So I would suggest "advancing bisonlike against the wind."

Answer (score 2):

When seeing people "walk", when wind is especially strong, it always seemed to me they :

1. **wade** - to walk through water, snow, sand, or any other substance that impedes free motion or offers resistance to movement:

or

2. **trudge** - to walk laboriously or wearily along or over:

taken from dictionary.com

Answer (score 2):

"forge" usually followed by
"ahead"
"through"
"forward

> forge
>   1. To advance gradually but steadily: forged ahead through throngs of shoppers.
>  [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/forge)
>
> 1.to move at a steady and persevering pace
>  [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/forge)
>
> 1 : to move forward slowly and steadily
>  the ship forged ahead
>   through heavy seas 
>  [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/forge)

Example:

> "Forged forward against the heavy winds."

Answer (score 0):

**tear oneself free** [merriam webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tear%20oneself%20loose/free) idiom

> to pull oneself away from someone or something

I sense this idiom lends itself to a fierce something, as in a fierce, strong wind, as in:

> She struggled to walk, stumbling to **tear herself free** of the winds
>   of the fierce storm!